# How to decode bytes from file that contains strings in java?

Tags: java, byte, decoding

I have a file that contains a string followed by bytes that contain binary numbers encoded in them.

```
Thisisastring. �J
```

In my code I try to ignore the string and focus on decoding the bytes that are separated by a space. When I run the code the outcome seems to be correct except the first binary number is off by a lot.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    File file = new File(arg);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8");
    Reader inn = new BufferedReader(isr);
    int ch;

    while ((ch = inn.read()) > -1){
        buffer.append((char)ch);
    }

    inn.close();

    String content = buffer.toString();
    String temp = new String();
    for(int i=0; i<content.length(); i++){
        temp += content.charAt(i);
        if(content.charAt(i) == ' '){
            while(i != content.length()-1){
                i++;
                byte b = (byte) content.charAt(i);
                String x = Integer.toString(b & 0xFF, 2);
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
11111101 <- Why is only this one incorrect?
11000
1001010
1011
```

What is expected:

```
10010101
00011000
01001010
1011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Readers` or `Strings` for binary data.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
File file = new File(arg);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
int ch;

while ((ch = din.read()) > -1){
    buffer.append((char)ch);
    if (ch == ' ')
    {
        // next byte is a binary value
        byte b = din.readByte();
        String x = Integer.toString(b & 0xFF, 2);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```